# Lisp symbols not highlighted correctly

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

Exhibit A:

[image]

The symbol `d_n+1` is highlighted as the variable `d_n`, operator+, and 1. This is incorrect; the symbol should be all one color.

Comment: This will probably have a higher chance of getting fixed if you report this on the [prettify issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/list).

Answer (score 5):

First, make sure the correct language highlighter is being used.

If the question is tagged [lisp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisp) that should be correct, but verify that the code class is correct in Google Chrome inspector.

For example on [Cube root (Newton's method)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1401/scheme-cube-root-newtons-method) which is tagged [lisp](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lisp) and [scheme](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scheme) I see the divs correctly have `lang-lisp` on them:

[image]

If this is not the case, **try to fix the tags first** and remember diamond mods can change the prettify language per-tag on the tag page.

If it's not fixable through tags (say the question is tagged [language-agnostic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic) or something) then you can [manually specify the language](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63800/interface-options-for-specifying-language-prettify), like so

```
<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->

    code goes here
```

It's very important you have the linebreak there.

If you've done this and the highlighting is still weird, indeed it must be filed as a bug against [Google Code Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/).

Comment: The [question in question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1373/common-lisp-compute-geometric-series) is definitely highlighted as lisp (it says `<pre class="lang-lisp prettyprint">` in the HTML source and everything else in the code sample (e.g. the `defun` keyword which is pretty lisp specific) is highlighted correctly). So this is indeed a bug in prettify's lisp highlighting.